# Experience on analog chaos based qc?

Tags: experimental-realization

Any expirience on applied analog qc using a chaos based approach. By chaos I mean using analog components in chaos state thus changing between a wide range of states simultanously.

The initial work on chaos(theory) was using analog electrical circuits and not only computers. Thus one could imagine that a analog (quantum) circuit could be created to solve a specific problem e.g. TSP.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Could you please be more specific? Also explaining what you mean by chaos-based would be helpful.

Comment: Updated question